# Allow Protobuf message to set null value

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I am wondering if it would be possible to detect a protobuf value being set to null rather than just not set at all. For example if we have:

```
message MyRequest {
    oneof my_value_case {
        string my_value = 1;
    }
}
```

I would want the request `{ "my_value": null }` to have `MyValueCase.MY_VALUE` rather than `MyValueCase.NOT_SET`.

Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out the [optional](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/proto3/#specifying-rules) keyword. I do not know the implementation in Java, but in C++, you will get a flag if the field is even to its default (empty) value.